# Are neural networks smart enough to overcome unbalanced data sets?

Tags: neural-networks, cross-validation, conv-neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

From what I have read, many models have issues with unbalanced data sets in classification problems.  Are neural networks smart enough to overcome this flaw or should I still look into creating a balanced data set.  I am able to feed the model a lot of data, but it will be unbalanced.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question 'Is X smart enough to produce a good model even when the dataset is imbalanced?' does not really depend on the model class you are choosing. Rather it is about whether (and if so, how) you tell that training routine about the imbalancedness. For example: If we have 100 data rows and 99 of them are negative and one of them is positive and the measure that we are using is accuracy then, yes, NNs (like any other model) can achieve a very high score (namely 99% accuracy) on that dataset by always predicting 'FALSE'. So it is about the performance measure and not about the model.

EDIT: To make this more clear: many models have this parameter class_weight, so in their natural form, they are nnot smart enough but when using an adapted loss function, they magically become smart enough... that's why I am saying that it does not depend on the model (class) but rather on how you train them...

As so many other models, NNs are being trained in the following way: Given all the data, regard the weights as parameters, form a loss function and then do gradient descent with that loss function. One way of telling the model about the imbalancedness is to change the loss function. For example one could create a loss function where the misclassification of the rare (in the example above: positive) class is being punished a lot more than a misclassification of the majority class. For NNs you can take a look at this post: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/13490/how-to-set-class-weights-for-imbalanced-classes-in-keras

However, one should say that mathematically speaking, this is actually the same as oversampling the minority class in the training set (because a misclassification of a single example actually means misclassification of many examples because the others reside at exactly the same place) and is independent of the library (i.e. is it calles class_weights or classWeights or ... --> you need to figure out for every new model class), so I would go for oversampling if the amount of data does permit that.

Comment: Ok, so it really depends on the optimization critieria.  That link is perfect as I want to use keras for implementation.